# NHibernate - does NHibernate recognise object equality and change is save behaviour accordingly?

Tags: nhibernate, insert, equality

Let's say you have two classes, Person and Address.

Person has a reference to Address like this:

```
public class Person
{
  public virtual Address Residence {get;set;}
}
```

Address has an override of .Equals which determines whether two Address instances represent the same physical address (by comparing postcode and first line, say).

Let's say you have two unsaved Person objects which hold references to two unsaved Address objects, which are separate (in terms of reference equality) but equal in terms of .Equals implementation.

Will NHibernate issue one INSERT or two?

Thanks

David

Comment: Is Address an entity (eg. a mapped class with its own table) or a value object (eg. mapped as a component and stored in the Person table?)

Comment: It's an entity in its own right. The database is highly normalised (not great for NHibernate I'm starting to guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will insert twice. Having it match two *transient* instances by equality is not technically possible.

The calling code would be responsible for matching those instances and replacing them by the same reference.